# JDBC Auto-Commit Not Working with PostgreSQL 9 Driver

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc

I have a spring application with a PostgreSQL DataSource loaded from JDNI:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/DB" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

I hooked it up with a JDBCTemplate

```
// DataSource is Autowired
jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

and auto-commit is set to true

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="postgres" password="localPostgres"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          defaultAutoCommit="true"/>
```

When I try to insert an item with a simple SQL insert statement the changes are not committed to the database.

```
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO items (name, surname) VALUES ('samantha', 'catania')";
```

Entering the SQL statement directly in the database console the item gets inserted i.e. the SQL is correct.

Any ideas what could be the issue please?

Comment: Post relevant code please.

Comment: Maybe some Spring magic around it. Are you using the `@Transactional` annotation? What is the _complete_ code that runs the DML statement?

Comment: Adding `@Transactional` didn't help unfortunately. The DML satement is coded as such: `public void insertItem(Item item) {
        getJdbcTemplate().update(item.getSQLInsert());
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was happening because I am using Spring Batch and my commits where being done within the transaction created by Spring Batch. Adding `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)` to my method fixes the issues.
This [article](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/java/common-oversights-utilizing-nested-transactions-spring/) describes common pitfalls when using `@Transactional` which helped me find a solution for my problem.